# whitespace on top of shiny dashboard

Tags: css, shiny, shinydashboard, removing-whitespace

I'm trying to create a shiny dashboard page and whenever I put text into dashboard body part, there is a huge chunk of whitespace that I would like to remove. Here is a picture of the dashboard:

[image]

There's the spacing between the testing and the top bar. I'm wondering how I can remove that spacing? Of course I don't want it to be all crammed/close together, but I don't want a huge block of whitespace at the top. Here is my coding for the dashboard:

```
dashboardHeader(title = "Title"),

dashboardSidebar(width = 270,
  sidebarMenu(
    menuItem("Home", tabName = "home", icon = icon("home"))
  ),

dashboardBody(
    tabItem(tabName = "home", 
            h4("testing")
    )
)
```

I've tried to do a css file and do `padding-top` and `margin`, it didn't work out and turned out messy. Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

h1, h2, h3, h4 generally come with a margin-top.

try css-

```
h4 {
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm.

Comment: Glad I could help :)